# how to choose mongo shard key selection for file system like structure

Tags: mongodb

I have a system where users save metadata of files, 
the system serves different companies, each can have up to millions of files arranged in a classic folder structure

I need to choose a shard key, any directions on that ?

Answer (score 1):

To prevent queries from having to check all the shards for results, the shard-key should be something which appears in each of your find- or update-queries. In a multi-client solution I would expect that the company is part of each query, so the company would make a good shard-key. When your companies have very different usage-schemas and you notice that some of them have so heavy use that a single shard isn't enough for them, you could add the filename to the shard-key. But that's an optimization you can't consider before you have real-world usage statistics.

For further advise, consult the chapter [Considerations for Selecting Shard Keys](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/choose-a-shard-key/) from the documentation.